# Saving the Output in a new excel file

Tags: vba, excel

I want to save my final output sheet in to a new excel file and I have created a button to execute this.

```
Set NewBook = Workbooks.Add
Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Output")
Do
    fName = Application.GetSaveAsFilename
Loop Until fName <> False
ws.Copy Before:=NewBook.Sheets(1)
NewBook.SaveAs Filename:=fName & Excel.XlFileFormat.xlOpenXMLWorkbook
NewBook.Close
```

The code is saving the output file in a windows shell or any unkbown format. How can I modify it to save the file in a excel format(without macros) and then close it automatically?. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
NewBook.SaveAs Filename:=fName & ".XLSX", FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbook
```

1. You have to provide the file extension, Excel won't do it for you.
2. You needed to provide the format parameter as a parameter, not concatenated into the string (as pointed out by Sorceri)
3. You specified the first parameter by naming it, all subsequent parms must be named
4. You only need to specify the enumeration name, not the complete object path to it

Answer (score 2):

you are using save as wrong

```
NewBook.SaveAs fName, Excel.XlFileFormat.xlOpenXMLWorkbook
```

Comment: Even after changing it, it  does not save it in excel formal. I even  tried xlnormal and xldefault format.